# Mock @org.jboss.seam.annotations.in behaviour for unittest

Tags: seam, testng, mockito

The test:

```
public class BeanTest {

    private SomeBean target;

    @Test(groups = "integration")
    public void checkIfAuthenticationWorks() {

        ApplicationBean applicationBean = mock(ApplicationBean.class);
        target = new SomeBean();

        // Some cool code to inject applicationBean to target class

        assertEquals("token", target.authenticate(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
    }
}
```

The class:

```
@AutoCreate
@Name("someBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
public class someBean implements Serializable {

    @Logger
    private static Log log;

    @In
    ApplicationBean applicationBean;

    public String authenticate(String username, String password) {

     // Very cool code!

    return "token";
    }
}
```

Is there some smart way of solving the applicationBean injection part?

// Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the test the Seam way, that is extending `SeamTest`:

```
public class BeanTest extends SeamTest {

    private SomeBean target;

    @Test(groups = "integration")
    public void checkIfAuthenticationWorks() {

        target = (SomeBean) Component.getInstance(SomeBean.class);
        // target get injected with the MockApplicationBean


        assertEquals("token", target.authenticate(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
    }
}
```

Then, create a `MockApplicationBean` with `MOCK` precedence and put it in the test classpath so that it will be injected in place of the real `ApplicationBean`:

```
@Name("applicationBean")
@Install(precedence = MOCK)
public class MockApplicationBean extends ApplicationBean
{
  // your mocked ApplicationBean  

}
```

Finally, note that `target` must be instantiated as a Seam component, not with "new":

```
SomeBean target = (SomeBean) Component.getInstance(SomeBean.class);
```