# Mocking at compile time

Tags: java, mocking, seam, integration-testing, mockito

I'm working with some legacy code and I need to test that some expensive service is called (it makes network calls, send emails, etc.).

I'm able to inject a fake service instead of the original one by means of the framework in use (jboss seam 2). See this question: [Mock @org.jboss.seam.annotations.in behaviour for unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538754/mock-org-jboss-seam-annotations-in-behaviour-for-unittest)

I now want my fake object to be a smarter mock to assert if it has been called or not, etc. I would like it to be a Mockito or Easymock or some other thing mock. But constructing the mock the classical way in the test and then injecting it, is not working because of the way seam 2 and seam test deals with injection. See the link above.

Question: is there a way to have my mock extend or be annotated in order to become a Mockito or something mock? How can I get a reference to it in my tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree with the answer of the question you linked to. A unit test should test the class independantly from the environment it's supposed to work in. And dependency injection frameworks are precisely used to be able to inject mock dependencies in unit tests, without needing any complex environment to run the unit test.

I don't know Seam, but its documentation says that @In can be placed on a property accessor. I would just have the class under test like this:

```
public class someBean implements Serializable {
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean

    @In
    protected void setApplicationBean(ApplicationBean applicationBean) {
        this.applicationBean = applicationBean;
    }
    ...
}
```

And I would just call the setter to inject the mock in the unit test.

You could also let the code as is, but provide a setter or an additional constructor to be able to inject a mock applicationBean.

Comment: I agree, but I've already tried this approach and the injection didn't work. The linked question/answer is based on seam reference. I'll try once more your suggestion maybe I'm missing some small stuff :)

Comment: How could something like this not work: `ApplicationBean mockApplicationBean = mock(ApplicationBean.class); SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean(); someBean.setApplicationBean(mockApplicationBean);` It's plain old Java. If it doesn't work, then the setter has a bug. Seam is not used at all with this approach.

Comment: It seems to work, no exceptions, but it's using the normal class not the mock.

Comment: If ApplicationBean is a concrete class, and you don't configure the mock to do anything other than what the concrete class does, then of course the real methods are used. You need to configure the mock before using it: `when(mockApplicationBean.someMethod()).thenReturn(5);`

Comment: I managed to make/hack it working. Seam dependency injects fields before every method call (I'm doing integration testing). So it was useless to do a setApplicationBean before calling the action method. But when injecting, it searches its contexts (event, request, conversation, etc.) for an existing component. The solution is to replace the real component with the mock one on the conversation context. Thanks JB Nizet for keeping me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You need a class with the same name but a higher precedence.  I've built plenty of mocks just doing that.

You give the same @name to your mock class and you define @install(precedence=MOCK). As soon as this class is in the classpath it will be used instead of your normal class (precedence default is application if I remember correctly). 
I have no code ready here just now but I mock the facesmessage for example so during testing I can read these messages from this class and validate them.